# Gruntjs angularjs cordova image not loading up

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, gruntjs

Not sure what I am doing wrong. 
This is how my css looks like after grunt but my actual image filename is

backgorund-with-logo.d623d8e2.jpg

```
.containor{
    min-height: 100%; 
    background: url('/images/backgorund-with-logo.d623d8e2.jpg') center 30% no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Gruntfile

```
usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']

            }
        },
imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        },
```

But when i try to run on my android device and inspect through chrome 
Failed to load resource file:///images/backgorund-with-logo.d623d8e2.jpg

Please help

Comment: Can you verify the image name is backgorund-with-logo.jpg and not background-with-logo.jpg. Also is the problem specific to android?

Comment: filename is fine. I have looked into the image folder and image exists. This is happening for both android and ios

Comment: if I am not wrong it should load image from file:///android_asset/www/images/... but not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach but I blocked minifying image by removing '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}', from filerev. If there is a better approach, please let us know